# Why does Wordpress import insert spurious end-tags?

Tags: wordpress, import, markup

I hit this problem with the venerable (but functioning) HTML Importer plugin, and assumed it was specific to that.  However, I then mimicked the format of a Wordpress export XML file, and imported that, and got exactly the same error.

The page I'm importing has images coded as links, thus:

```
<div id="e8"><p><a href="/meetings_0907"><figure class="wp-caption aligncenter"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/poster_0907-216x305-1.jpg" width="216" height="305" border="0" alt="A Hundred Years of Change, 27 September 2007"/><figcaption class="wp-caption-text">A Hundred Years of Change, 27 September 2007</figcaption></figure></a></p></div>
```

When imported, they acquire spurious paragraph end- and start-tags, thus:

```
<div id="e8">
<p><a href="/meetings_0907"></p>
<figure class="wp-caption aligncenter"><img loading="lazy" src="/wp-content/uploads/poster_0907-216x305-1.jpg" width="216" height="305" border="0" alt="A Hundred Years of Change, 27 September 2007"/><figcaption class="wp-caption-text">A Hundred Years of Change, 27 September 2007</figcaption></figure>
<p></a></p>
</div>
```

I would be happy to adjust my markup so that it is more Wordpress-friendly, if that would solve the parsing error which is clearly happening.

Richard

Comment: Your markup is not exactly valid.  WordPress is probably trying to make sense of the <a> and <p> tags.  Try running through this: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input you'll see.

Comment: Thanks: validating the HTML proved to be the way to resolve the issue. Though I'm slightly surprised to learn that HTML 5 doesn't have a DTD, and doesn't feel it needs one.